# Are there any VBScript libraries?

Tags: vbscript, libraries

Are there any open source free VBScript libraries? I am doing a lot of windows administration and always find myself writing error prone code. Any help here?

Answer (score 3):

You really should move to [powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx).

I haven't heard of a sysadmin working in vbscript in quite a long time.

**update**
There used to be several sites that hosted script libraries, like [win32scripting](http://cwashington.netreach.net/), but they've been rapidly disappearing due to powershell.

You might go check out [The Scripting Guy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/default.aspx).  They have a section just for VBScript in their [forums](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=ScriptLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Value=VBScript&f%5B0%5D.Text=VBScript) that may be of help.

Comment: I really wish a could. I don't have permission to use powershell as it is blocked where im at.

Comment: There are still people who have to use VBScript, although PowerShell is really taking over, especially in the last year or so.

Comment: @Luke101: that royally sucks.

Answer (score 3):

Even 5 years after the post above was written it is still short sighted and doesn't answer the question.

Admins need to work in whatever language is available and suitable -- some of us with LARGE (1000s) server or client estates still have quite a bit of Win2003, Win2000, and even a few NT4 servers.

I dislike VBScript somewhat but write using it, since it is the only language besides CMD.exe batch that is ubiquitously available on all Microsoft systems from NT4 on forward.

Even our Win2003 servers don't typically have PowerShell.

Libraries:
  http://sourceforge.net/projects/vbslib/

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12028

https://code.google.com/p/vbslib/

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech.php

http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/vbscript/